# why do I get error when installing package in R?

Tags: java, r, package

I am trying to install and run 'KoNLP' in my local R server.
but somehow I am keep getting error as below

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘KoNLP’:
    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'KoNLP', details:
    call: fun(libname, pkgname)
    error: You cann't parse resource files based on UTF-8 on rJava. 
    Please reload KoNLP first than any other packages connected with 
    rJava.
```

I installed java and assigned java home using

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = 
 '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/jre')
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
```

I don't know why I am keep getting this error.
Can some one please help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dir.exists(paste(Sys.getenv("PROGRAMFILES"), "\\Java\\", sep = ""))){
  Javapath <- paste(Sys.getenv("PROGRAMFILES"), "\\Java\\", sep = "")
  Javapath <- paste(Javapath, list.files(path = Javapath, pattern = "jdk"), "\\",sep = "")
  if(grepl("jdk", Javapath)){
    options(java.home=Javapath[which.max(gsub(".*jdk[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+_|\\\\$", "", Javapath))])
  }else{
    Javapath <- paste(Sys.getenv("PROGRAMFILES"), "\\Java\\", sep = "")
    Javapath <- paste(Javapath, list.files(path = Javapath, pattern = "jre"), "\\",sep = "")
    options(java.home=Javapath[which.max(gsub(".*jre[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+_|\\\\$", "", Javapath))])
  }
}else if(dir.exists(paste(Sys.getenv("PROGRAMFILES(x86)"), "\\Java\\", sep = ""))){
  Javapath <- paste(Sys.getenv("PROGRAMFILES(x86)"), "\\Java\\", sep = "")
  Javapath <- paste(Javapath, list.files(path = Javapath, pattern = "jre"), "\\",sep = "")
  options(java.home=Javapath[which.max(gsub(".*jre[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+_|\\\\$", "", Javapath))])
}
```

Maybe u can try to set options(java.home="path to java")